# Azure DevOps select variable template based on condition

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

What is the correct syntax for getting variable template based on condition? What I am trying and which does not work

```
variables:
  - template: Variables/vars.yml
  - ${{ if eq(variables.System, 'Cat Dog') }}:
    - template: 'Templates/CD.yml'
      parameters:
        Name: ${{ variables.name }}


  - ${{ if eq(variables.System, 'Sheep Wooly') }}:
    - template: 'Templates/SW.yml'
      parameters:
        Name: ${{ variables.name }}


  - ${{ if eq(variables.System, 'Falcon Fly') }}:
    - template: 'Templates/FF.yml'
      parameters:
        Name: ${{ variables.name }}

stages:
- stage: Prepare
  displayName: "Prepare barn"
  variables:
    - template: Templates\${{ variables.SystemShort }}.yml
  jobs:  
  - job: Prepare
    displayName: "Prepare"
    steps:
    - task: AzurePowershell@5
      displayName: Prepare
      inputs: 
        azureSubscription: '${{ variables.azureSubscription}}'
        scripttype: filepath
        scriptpath: 'scripts/Prepare.ps1'
        scriptArguments:
          -Name ${{ variables.Name }}
        azurePowerShellVersion: latestVersion
        pwsh: true
```

vars.yml

```
variables:
  System: Cat Dog
  SystemShort: CD
  Name: Todd
```

And the error message I get is "Missing an argument for parameter 'Name'" suggesting my fed in scriptargument is empty.

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Do you get a syntax error? An issue at runtime?

Comment: I am trying to put the "Name" variable into my script in the next stage PowerShell does not recognize it as string most likely being empty

Comment: You need to share your entire pipeline and explain *exactly where and how* it's not working. Your explanation isn't clear.

Comment: Fair point. I have added more of the pipeline

Comment: Try downloading the expanded yml file to see how the values are being populated. This should show how the values are there.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: After the pipeline has ran failed or completed. select the individual run, click the three dots and select download logs. From there open the .zip and find the file azure-pipeline-expanded.yml. This should show the template fully expanded w/ all variables.[Full steps can be found](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/azure-devops-pipelines-templates-tasks-and-jobs/ba-p/3712459)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want:

```
- ${{ if eq(variables.System, 'Sheep Wooly') }}:
    - template: 'Templates/SW.yml'
```

You don't need to individual call out the values as the pipeline will expand and pull in the values from your template. Values would be reference with a regular syntax such as ${{ variables.Name }}.

Here is a [MS blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/healthcare-and-life-sciences/azure-devops-pipelines-environments-and-variables/ba-p/3707414) that could help as well.

Comment: I downvoted this because *you don't know that this is the problem*. The templates may very well have a `parameter` named `name`; it's perfectly valid and in fact is generally preferable rather than hoping that your consuming template happens to have a variable defined. The original question didn't specify what *doesn't work* means, so your "answer" is speculative and most likely isn't correct.